# PHP create file in mapped drive directory

Tags: php, windows, apache, codeigniter, wamp

Trying to create a file into a folder in the mapped drive (Z:)

The source code Im using is as follows:

```
$fileNumber = 'F2310XXXX';
$content = "; Test \n; Date : ".date('d/m/Y H:i:s')."\n; Filename : ".$fileNumber.".TXT";
$fp = fopen("//xx.xx.xxx.xxx/MC/".$fileNumber.".TXT","wb");
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
```

The following error occur:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning. 
Message: fopen(//xx.xx.xxx.xxx/MC/F2310XXXX.TXT): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Filename: controllers/Auth.php

Line Number: 76

Backtrace:

File: C:\wamp64\www\mc-app\admin\application\controllers\Auth.php
Line: 76
Function: fopen

File: C:\wamp64\www\mc-app\admin\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

**Please someone help to solve this issue as I tried almost all the solutions got it from google but no luck. All your help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance**

Comment: I was going to mention that mapped drives are per-user, but then noticed that the only mention to `Z:` to be found here is in the question itself, not in your code :-?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Instead of ``Z:`` I use server address for the same.

Comment: Make sure that the user Apache runs as has access to that share.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes the Apache run as administrator

Answer (score 0):

If you know the drive letter why not specify it?

```
$fp = fopen("Z:/MC/".$fileNumber.".TXT","wb");
```

Without it you are trying to open that file on the default script located drive.

Is the xx.xx.xxx.xxx an IP address?

The issue is almost without fail a permissions issue.

Comment: Since I'm guessing that `xx.xx.xxx.xxx` means the IP for the share, it should either be `Z:` or `/xx.xx.xxx.xxx/`, not both. And it might not be that simple anyway, since the PHP application runs through Apache (based on their tag), which will run on another user that might not have that drive mapped.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. Even if I keep the drive letter it didn't work. And xx.xx.xxx.xxx is IP address of machine.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yeah correct.. So how can we tackle this?

Comment: I take it this is running on a Windows subsystem. Using Z:/MC/... will work as long as the user has write permissions to that folder on Z:.

Comment: @GuySchwartz I tried creating file inside MC manually, and its working. So I think the user have permission to that folder.